# unix get list of all occurences of string between two quotes

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file Like this

```
"Logs timestamps are good =timstamp= for new files check data=
new-char= the data is changed every =time and=

so on and i need all =data="
```

eof

I want to capture all the strings starting with "=" and ending with "="  so output should be like 'new-char' 'time and' 'data' i am not able to get it some how
i tried running
`sed -n '/=/,/=/p'` and
`sed -n '/\=/,/\=/p'`
both of it does not give me the required output not sure what's wrong .. please advise

Comment: did you wanna perl solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tr -d '\n' < file | sed -r -e 's/(=[^=]+)=/\1\n/g' | sed -n 's/.*=//p'
```

**Step by step:**

**Original:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ cat file
"Logs timestamps are good =timstamp= for new files check data=
new-char= the data is changed every =time and=

so on and i need all =data="
```

**1:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ tr -d '\n' < file
"Logs timestamps are good =timstamp= for new files check data=new-char= the data is changed every =time and=so on and i need all =data="sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$
```

**2:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ tr -d '\n' < file | sed -r -e 's/(=[^=]+)=/\1\n/g'
"Logs timestamps are good =timstamp
 for new files check data=new-char
 the data is changed every =time and
so on and i need all =data
"sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$
```

**3:**

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$ tr -d '\n' < file | sed -r -e 's/(=[^=]+)=/\1\n/g' | sed -n 's/.*=//p'
timstamp
new-char
time and
data
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/^[^=]*(=[^=]*=)/\1\n/;/^=/P;D' file
```

Slurp the file into memory, remove all the newlines, remove non-essential strings and print out each required string on a newline.